# CSS Flexbox: how to reorder divs in one column to reflow to two columns on screen resize

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I'm very new at using Flexbox and not sure it will solve my problem.

I have a layout of a 940px width with 3 columns @ 300px each (required).  On medium to large screens, the first row contains 2 columns (one column @ 600px) and the third column (300px) containing two div stacked vertically.  On small screens I need the 600px div to reflow full width, with the 300px divs to reflowing horizontally (side-by-side) on the next row.  On smallest screens, I need all to stack vertically.  I know there are ways I can do this using floats, but then I run into multiple specialty classes and I want to use reusable css class rules due to javascript `for...each` statements written by other developers.  Therefore, I'm wondering if flexbox could provide me with a responsive solution using reusable classes for the divs that will repeat. Here's what I have so far.

**HTML**

```
        <div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex-item flex-item--1">1</div>
      <div class="flex-container-inner">
       <div  class="flex-item flex-item--2">2</div>
      <div  class="flex-item flex-item--3">3</div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="flex-container">
       <div class="flex-item">4</div>
      <div class="flex-item">5</div>
      <div class="flex-item">6</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.content {
  width: 940px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.flex-item {
  background: #abc;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.flex-item--1 {
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.flex-item--2 {
  height: 75px;
}
.flex-item--3 {
  height: 55px;
}
  @media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) 
  { 
 }
 @media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
  .flex-item--1 {
    flex: 2 0px;
  }
  .flex-item--2 {
    order: 1;
  }
  .flex-item--1 {
    order: 2;
  }
  .flex-item--3 {
    order: 3;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 959px) and (max-width: 1023px) {}

  @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {}
```

This is what I need it to look like on resize 768px - 959px.
[image]

**[CODEPEN Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KaZrQV)**

**UPDATE**

Here is the full layout at various screensizes.  I misunderstand Flexbox, I thought the divs would flow responsively if I added more, but they are not. I also replaced `li` with `divs`.   Will I need to use a lot of media queries to target these to reflow responsively as pictured below:
[image: full layout with additional divs added]

Comment: In your css I see you try to put item 1 between item 2 and 3, but that will not be possible without script since they aren't siblings

Comment: Ok.  I revised the  example on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), I see that doesn't work, so I'm looking for help here.  Please feel free to revise the code.  Thanks.

Comment: From largest to smallest, total number of boxes decrement by 1 (e.g. largest = 6 boxes, medium = 5 boxes, and smallest = 4 boxes.) Is this by design and if so, does one merge into another so content is still present? Or does the box disappear along with content?

Comment: @zer00ne, thanks.  I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.  The images above show the design spec: 3 - 2 -1...  Nothing is merging into another and no content is disappearing.  I'm trying to use 1 (at the most 2) reusable classes that can be put into a javascript loop to build out the UI dynamically, but the 940/3 dimensions just don't work well, imo.

Comment: Hi @Chris22 I mean you lose one box when going down a size. Do you always want 6 boxes or does it matter?

Comment: @zer00ne thanks.  Ah, I see what you mean.  Each row contains 3-columns at wide width.  I've been looking at this code so long I'm missing the obvious... I'll adjust my code above.

Comment: @Chris22 indeed, many times a pair of fresh eyes saved me hours of toil.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134433/discussion-between-chris22-and-zer00ne).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I have it this time.

Notes of explanation:

1. I set your workspace to `box-sizing: border-box`. This automatically deducts margins so you don't have to manually set `.content { width: [container minus margins] }`.
2. I restructured your media queries so that your "base" design was for the smallest screen and you go up from there. Most tutorials say this is best practice, and it's what's most straightforward for me. This shouldn't be too hard for you to change if you don't like it. On a related note, I got rid of all your `and (max-width: [whatever])` queries because it's redundant without a specific reason.
3. I'm not very good with the prefixes/alternate syntax (the `-webkit-` and whatnot) so I just left those out lest I steer you wrong. They're pretty easy to add in.
4. I used `%` for all the widths so that it would be easier to see the logic/relationships at a glance. I also consider this better for media queries since there are a lot of screen size variations particularly in mobile. But that's pretty easy to adjust with your specific values.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zNpgpJ

Comment: I have divs #2 and #3 in a container div to have them stack vertically in one column, when I removed the container div, div #3 flows to the next row at screens > 1024px. codepen. I'm going to keep at it, but I'm not understanding how, according to your answer,  #3 would "know" it's in the same "column" as #2 and then to stack vertically directly under it...

Comment: Okay, I missed the Codepen link and I didn't actually answer the full question. I'm about to rewrite my answer, but one thing I'm not clear about, is that your drawings have different numbers of blocks, 6 then 5 then 4. Are some intended to disappear at smaller screen sizes?

Comment: thanks, no worries I overlooked to add rows.  It's 3-column per row ([updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KaZrQV)). No columns disappear. I also don't know why on resize, the layout is shifting to the left instead of remaining centered on the code "page" view.